# If $T:V\to W$ is linear, prove that $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle T(x), T(y)\rangle$ defines an inner product on $V$ iff $T$ is one-to-one.

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $F(=\mathbb{R} ~\text{or}~\mathbb{C}), $ and let $W$ be an inner product space over $F$ with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $. If $T:V\to W$ is linear, prove that $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle T(x), T(y)\rangle$ defines an inner product on $V$ iff $T$ is one-to-one.

I have tried to test all the axioms for inner product space but that does not help me to solve this problem. This seems not very tough but I am unable to hit at the right idea. So please pardon my inability to show my work as there is none to write down. Please help me to solve this. Any idea, hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Which part(s) have you problems with? It's basically just verification. Check that $(x,y) \mapsto \langle T(x), T(y)\rangle$ is sesquilinear, and then when it's positive definite.

Comment: Suppose $T$ is one to one then I need to show that the above define function is an inner product. Then how should I approach? Do I have to show that is satisfies all the axioms ?

Comment: It's simplest to split the thing into two parts. First show that it's a hermitian sesquilinear (symmetric bilinear) form, regardless of whether $T$ is injective or not. Then take the second step, show that this sesquilinear form is positive definite if and only if $T$ is injective.

Comment: ok let me try ..

Comment: Did you manage? If so, please consider posting an answer.